# Why do planets in Star Wars only have one environment?

Tags: star-wars, planets

This thought came to me concerning the *Star Wars* universe.

On our planet (Earth) we have many different habitats (snowy wastelands, forests, cities); but in the Star Wars universe there only appears to be be one kind of environment per planet, e.g: Hoth is snowy, Endor is all forest and Coruscant is city.

Why is this?

Comment: "City" isn't an environment?

Comment: I'm trying to think of an episode where you see more than a small part of the planet? What I'm saying is that if the story demanded that only a small part of the planet was shown, you wouldn't know the difference between that and the planet only having one environment

Comment: Related: [How do all the planets in the Star Wars universe contain breathable atmosphere and Earth gravity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113631/70236)